# Updating state on Next.js router query change causes infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

Let me give you some context:

I'm trying to mutate some data on the server with React Query's `useMutation` (You can think of it as setting a local state because the behavior is the same to some extent).

But the mutation that I want to make should be dependent on having some query param on the `router.query`.

So for example, if `router.query.token` is set (is not falsy or undefined), then the mutation should happen.

Now I know we can use an Effect to achieve something like that. That way you won't get an infinite loop:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (router?.query?.token) {
    sampleMutation({
      sampleData: "Sample Data",
      ...router.query,
    });
  }
}, [router?.query?.token, sampleMutation]);
```

I was wondering if there's another way of implementing this without the use of an Effect.

Since all the solutions I've tried caused an infinite loop.

One of the solutions I've tried was something like this, which caused an infinite loop:

https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#adjusting-some-state-when-a-prop-changes

I now recognize that my approach may have been completely wrong, so I'm attempting to explore if there's any alternative to using an Effect for this situation.

Comment: I think is very strange that sample Mutation is on deps of your useEffect; perhaps it is the reason for loop. Is sampleMutation the second output value of an useState?

Comment: You could probably use [router.events](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerevents). Find the [example usage here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-loading/pages/_app.tsx)

Comment: @Max So the `sampleMutation` could be any state that is being set. But in our case, this is a real mutation made with `react-query`.
A simple implementation of that would be something like this:

`const { mutate: sampleMutation } = useMutation(someQueryFunction);`

And the thing is that the `sampleMutation` is a dependency on the Effect, and it should be included inside of that dependency array.

The Effect that I've included inside the question doesn't cause the infinite loop. I want to see if there's an alternative to the Effect that doesn't cause an infinite loop.

Comment: @vighnesh153 I still have to use the Effect. The React documentation tells me you might not need an Effect. I wanna know if there really is a need for an Effect in my case. Almost every Effect alternative that the React documentation has provided caused an infinite loop. I might've used those alternatives in the wrong way. That's why I asked the question here; To see if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking a lot about the question that I had, I finally came to this conclusion:

There's an alternative way, and I really don't need to use an Effect.

Let me explain the issue.

I wanted to use something like this instead of using an Effect:

```js
if (router?.query?.token) {
  sampleMutation({
    sampleData: "Sample Data",
    ...router.query,
  });
}
```

The issue was that when the `router.query.token` is set, well, it's always set! So the `sampleMutation` in this conditional happens over and over again.

The Effect made it so that the `sampleMutation` and the condition only happen once or re-render happens on a dependency change.

The only way to prevent the infinite loop was to actually get rid of the query param when it is set.

So imagine that this is our URL:

`http://localhost:3000/sample-url`

On this page, I'll click on a button and after the mutation is set a query param is added to the rest of the URL and it becomes something like this:

`http://localhost:3000/sample-url?token=12345`

This `token` query param which was `undefined` is not set to a value.

So, naturally, it makes an infinite loop inside this page (component) and the mutation (state) is being set over and over again.

To prevent this from happening, all I had to do was to get rid of the query param immediately after the mutation (state) is being set.

So this is my final approach:

```js
if (router?.query?.token) {
  sampleMutation({
    sampleData: "Sample Data",
    ...router.query,
  });
  router.replace('/sample-url', undefined, { shallow: true });
}
```

I was so confused, that I thought the mutation (state) is causing the infinite loop. It was rather the `router.query.token` itself.